# resolution of the original image from JPEG compression

Tags: image, file, compression, jpeg, resolution

JPEG compression of two images yields two 1MB and 2MB files. From these compressed files can we have an idea about the resolutions of the original images? How is that possible?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The resolution of the image is the same before and after JPEG compression. JPEG compression may change the resolution of one or more components with respect to another component (usually Y). At least one component has to be sampled at the original rate so the image resolution does not change.

A 50% difference in compression can result from the selection of quantization tables or (more likely) subsampling of components.